# sqlalchemy: multiple bases for the same class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is probably very straightforward, but still picking up sqlalchemy and can't seem to find an answer. I have a basic module sometable.py

```
import config
class SomeTable(config.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bla'
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now, I want to write a test on this module: basically add a few test rows, do some calculations using the other functions of SomeTable, and check the results. But i don't want to do these manipulations in my main database. how can i pass a different Base object to the class defined in sometable module? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

e.g. my test_sometable.py currently looks like this:

```
import sometable, config
class TestSomeTable(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
        self.Base = declarative_base(config.Base.metadata, engine)

    def test_some_functionality(self):
        tbl = sometable.SomeTable('name1')
        # if i create a session and add a row here, 
        # it will add it to my main database, rather than the in-memory one
```

Answer (score 1):

`SomeTable` uses `config.Base` as base, it doesn't matter that you define a new `Base` in your test class. How is your entity supposed to know that it should another base?

i think it should work if you first import `config`, then replace `config.Base` with the base you want to use and only after that import `sometable`. otherwise you have to find another way to use a test configuration instead of the production configuration when running your unittests.

Comment: Agreed, right now the entity has no way of using the new base i have defined: that's precisely the bit of code I am looking for. 
Using a different config specifically for running test isn't a bad idea, but I would have thought there is a natural way to have several instances of the same object point to different database ?

Comment: ended up adding a config.TEST flag, as well as a config.TestBase.
in the actual file, config.TEST is set to false.
in the setUp() of my test, i set the config.TEST to True and reload the module sometable. in tearDown() i set config.TEST back to false and TestBase to None.